# Using puppet master without SSL and certificate based authentication?

Tags: puppet

I want to try out puppet in my test environment. I am fine even if the communication between master and agent is insecure. I am also fine even if there is no authentication between master and agent. I understand the consequences of it. Is there a way to achieve it? Is it possible to disable certificate based authentication between client and master and also disable secure/encrypted communication between master and agent?

Comment: puppet design are based on ssl certification, unless you fork it and develop  with insecure-puppet by yourself.

Comment: Try to setup autosiging in puppet: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/ssl_autosign.html. I will not turn off authentication, but it will make you life with puppet much easier. Also consider enabling "duplicate certs" https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#allowduplicatecerts.